# how to show color points on google maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I have a google map (using php and java script).  I have the coordinates of all my location in My dataBase and just want to show many color points (green red... etc ) for each coordinate onclick on submint, any help

Answer (score 0):

You can use: 
- Javascript library called D3.js and integrate it the old way into the map using Google maps markers 
- Using overlays from Google Maps

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays